# How can I fit circles into a shape using python?

Tags: python

So for a project, I gotta make a web-site that fills a shape with circles that wont intersact at any point.The user is going to upload a shape, and also choose the radius of the circles, and the code is going to place as many circles(with the chosen radius) as it can into the shape.

For example, if the user uploads an 16cmx16cm square and chooses 4cm as the radius of the circles, the system is going to place as many circles with a radius of 4cm as possible into the square, and the circles wont intersact at any point.

I tried many things using python and failed eveytime. The shape can be anything, it can be completely random and no matter what the shape is, the site has to find out where to place the circles with the selected radius, place the circles, and show the final shape. I dont know if there is a way to do this without python, but I am open to every suggestion-solution.

Comment: Infinite amount of inifinitely small circles?

Comment: no, the user is gonna choose the radius, and the circles cannot intersect at any point so its not infinite @matszwecja

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to improve it @СергейКох ,hope its better now

Comment: how will the user's shape be defined? an image file? something like an [SVG path](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/shape-elements/#svg-path)?

Comment: an image file @Stuart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the package [circle-packing](https://github.com/xnx/circle-packing). It looks like you can get the behavior you want by setting the arguments `rho_max` and `rho_min` of the class `ShapeFill` to the radius provided by user. I've *not used* it so cannot attest to its' correctness or usability. Please let us know if it works for you.

Note: The license is [GPLV2](https://github.com/xnx/circle-packing/blob/master/LICENSE) so keep in mind the implications. And don't forget to attribute.

Comment: It seems like it will work, I will work on it, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe filling it with the actual possible maximum amount would be far from easy, if you actually just want fill it and don't care about the best solution then it's fairly easy.

just start to for the top left corner place a circle, if collides with another circle or the shape it, shift it to the right of an arbitrary small amount and try again. once you reached the end on the right side, move it down and to the left and start the process again.